# Unity - Get Component and Check for Null in One Line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to simplify the following block of code?

```
MyComponent myComponent = gameObject.GetComponent<MyComponent>();
if (myComponent != null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Something like

```
if (var myComponent = gameObject.GetComponent<MyComponent>() != null) {
    // do something
}
```

My motive for doing this is because I am raycasting a mouse press, and I want the type of the object that the user clicked on to affect what happens. For example, I would do something like

```
ComponentOne componentOne = gameObject.GetComponent<ComponentOne>();
if (componentOne != null)
{
    // do something
    return;
}

ComponentTwo componentTwo = gameObject.GetComponent<ComponentTwo>();
if (componentTwo != null)
{
    // do something
    return;
}

ComponentThree componentThree = gameObject.GetComponent<ComponentThree >();
if (componentThree != null)
{
    // do something
    return;
}
```

However, this is messy and unnecessarily lengthy.

Comment: Do these different components derive from a common base class (maybe not `Component` ^^) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for [TryGetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.TryGetComponent.html)

```
    if (TryGetComponent(out MyComponent myComponent))
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
MyComponent myComponent = gameObject.GetComponent<MyComponent>();
if (myComponent == null) return

// do something
```

Comment: this way you can avoid extra curly braces but still not a single line

Comment: In my specific case, I am raycasting a mouse press, and I want the functionality to change based on what type of object was clicked on. I'll update the question to be more clear.